# PARSE JSON WITH VBA

Tags: json, vba, ms-access

I need some help to parse this JSON result.

The idea is to get from `rates` the date value and the number.

For example:

`2018-01-03 : 9.825`

`2018-01-05 : 9.8318`

I am using JsonConverter in my code.

```json
{"rates":
{
    "2018-01-03":{"SEK":9.825},
    "2018-01-05":{"SEK":9.8318},
    "2018-01-02":{"SEK":9.8283},
    "2018-01-04":{"SEK":9.822}
},
"start_at":"2018-01-01",
"base":"EUR",
"end_at":"2018-01-05"}
```

Thanks for feedback.

Comment: What do you mean by saying `I am using JsonConverter in my code`?

Comment: I use this code.
https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    Dim parsedJSON As Dictionary
    Set parsedJSON = JsonConverter.ParseJson(yourJsonString)

    Dim rateKey As Variant
    For Each rateKey In parsedJSON("rates")
        Dim rate As Dictionary
        Set rate = parsedJSON("rates")(rateKey)
        Debug.Print rateKey, rate.Items(0)
    Next rateKey
```